# How to setup Apache tomcat and project to display UTF-8 text?

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, utf-8

I have problem with display text in jsp & servlet when deploy my project to apache tomcat (v8) (export .war file and copy to webapps in apache tomcat):

In web browser display after server responses:

**V?i 1 kh?n gi? b?ng ?? ph?n bi?t tr?ng t?i v?i th? m?n qua 2 li?n t??ng r?t...   nhi ??ng th?i tai: "?ng th?i c?i kh?ng d?m ?? b?ng v? ?ng ?eo g?ng hay ch? tr? l?c   ?? ph?t" nh? t?i, World Cup l? m?a m?t ng?. Trong khi c? nh? n?u m? xem b?ng   ?? v? h?ng x?m xung quanh c?ng cu?n theo nh?p b?ng l?n th? t?i cu?n... ch?n ?i  ng?**

Apache Tomcat console print:

**V?i 1 kh?n gi? b?ng ?? ph?n bi?t tr?ng t?i v?i th? m?n qua 2 li?n t??ng r?t...   nhi ??ng th?i tai: "?ng th?i c?i kh?ng d?m ?? b?ng v? ?ng ?eo g?ng hay ch? tr? l?c   ?? ph?t" nh? t?i, World Cup l? m?a m?t ng?. Trong khi c? nh? n?u m? xem b?ng   ?? v? h?ng x?m xung quanh c?ng cu?n theo nh?p b?ng l?n th? t?i cu?n... ch?n ?i   ng?**

How can I solve this problem?
Thank You in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `URIEncoding` attribute on the `<Connector>` element in server.xml is set to `URIEncoding="UTF-8"`.

[In order to completely switch to using UTF-8, you need to make the following changes:](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding)

Set URIEncoding="UTF-8" on your  in server.xml. References: HTTP Connector, AJP Connector.
Use a character encoding filter with the default encoding set to UTF-8

Change all your JSPs to include charset name in their contentType.

For example, use <%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %> for the usual JSP pages and  for the pages in XML syntax (aka JSP Documents).
Change all your servlets to set the content type for responses and to include charset name in the content type to be UTF-8.

Use response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8") or response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8").
Change any content-generation libraries you use (Velocity, Freemarker, etc.) to use UTF-8 and to specify UTF-8 in the content type of the responses that they generate.

Disable any valves or filters that may read request parameters before your character encoding filter or jsp page has a chance to set the encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: I tried! But it did not display correctly. When I run on eclipse it's good, but when I export it look like that!